# Can Fiddler change the return from Python Requests Module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, fiddler

If I make a request in Python 3 to grab the text of a webpage (Via Requests module), is it possible that someone using fiddler could change the response?

Answer (score 1):

short answer: Yes.

a bit longer: fiddler is an HTTP proxy, so if someone wants to intercept your traffic with it he needs to either:

a) configure it as a proxy in your code 

b) use some program on your computer that sends your traffic to fiddler

c) use some program  on your router that sends your traffic to fiddler

notice that only opening fiddler on your computer isn't enough for the script traffic to go through it, you need to configure it as a proxy in your requests at the code (for example: requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)).

Comment: So if I'm making an https request to grab the text of a page through python and a user doesn't have access to the source code, can they change the response then?

Comment: if the program runs on your computer, they probably can't.
if it's on their computer, they can.